# What is the difference between hasNext() and next()?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between `hasNext()` and `next()` and where it is used?
Is it used in Selenium WebDriver or Selenium IDE.

Comment: Voting for closing: This question is better placed in StackOverflow

Comment: This is an extremely basic coding question that will be downvoted to oblivion in StackOverflow. `hasNext()` checks whether the collection has any more elements, `next()` moves to the next elements in a collection. Neither have any relationship to Selenium. They are used in the programming language that is working with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I think Kannathasan has explained the difference perfectly, but I'd like to add some context:

Making the assumption that you're using Java, they're part of the Iterator interface as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

This interface is a part of Java.  While it has nothing to do with Selenium-Webdriver, parts of Selenium-Webdriver may implement it.

From the documentation:

**hasNext()**

```
boolean hasNext()

Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)

Returns:
    true if the iteration has more elements
```

**next()**

```
E next()

Returns the next element in the iteration.

Returns:
    the next element in the iteration
Throws:
    NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements
```

I can't think of a place in Selenium-Webdriver where I've used an iterator directly, but it's implemented in a few places where you could use it if you really wanted to.

If you have an ArrayList for example, you can access and use the Iterator instead of using a for loop.  There may be times where this is advantageous, but I can't think of any immediate examples.

Take this simple use with an ArrayList

```
 List <String> strings = new ArrayList <String>();

 strings.add("Example 1");
 strings.add("Example 2");

 Iterator<String> iterator = strings.iterator();

 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(iterator.next());
 }
```

While there are still items in the list to go through, it will print them out.  As there are 2 items in the list, it will run through 2 iterations and print out both strings that were added.

Answer (score 0):

hasNext is used to iterate the windows in selenium webdriver here is the difference

**hasNext()** will return true if iteration has more values

**next()** will return the next element in iteration